# SQL: Custom Sort Order

Tags: order-by

Suppose I have a column with colour names (`colour`). Naturally, it will be a character field.

I would like to sort the table by `colour`, but not in alphabetical order, but by rainbow or transistor colour code order.

What is the simplest way to sort a column using an arbitrary sort order? Something like this:

```
id  name        colour
1   this        red
4   that        red
2   stuff       orange
5   nonsense    orange
3   whatever    yellow
6   etc         yellow
```

where the colours in in rainbow order.

The use of colours is just an example. There are many sets of textual data where the order is not alphabetical.

Comment: Either create an explicit sort order table for each attribute that you want to order by, or use an implicit order relation such as: `select ... from ... order by case when color = 'red' then 1 when color = 'orange' then 2 when ... end`. Not sure why you have two id's per color in your example though.

Comment: @Lennart It was a simplified example. I have added another column to be more realistic. The point is that I would like to sort non-alphabetically. Surely there must be a simpler solution than using `case`?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I’m trying to keep this generic. Personally I use Postgres, but I often find myself using MSSQL & MariaDB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use another table with the key values (also suggested by @McNets) feel its less verbose and more scalable.

```
-----------------------------
|         Colours           |
-----------------------------
|  KeyValue  |    Name      |
-----------------------------
|     1      |  Red         |
|     2      |  Orange      |
|     3      |  Yellow      |
-----------------------------

-----------------------------
|        OtherTable         |
-----------------------------
| id |  Name    |  Colour   |
-----------------------------
| 1  | this     |   red     |
| 4  | that     |   red     |
| 2  | stuff    |   orange  |
| 5  | nonsense |   orange  |
| 3  | whatever |   yellow  |
| 6  | etc      |   yellow  |
-----------------------------

SELECT
    ot.Id,
    ot.Name,
    ot.Colour
FROM OtherTable ot
INNER JOIN Colours c on c.Name = ot.Colour
ORDER BY c.KeyValue
```

Comment: I’m inclined to agree. That was my first instinct, but I was hoping there was a slicker solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Use a case statement to establish the order, or add a lookup table with all colours where you can set an order.

> ```
> declare @t table(id int, name varchar(20), colour varchar(10));
> insert into @t values
> (1,   'this',        'red'),
> (4,   'that',        'red'),
> (2,   'stuff',       'orange'),
> (5,   'nonsense',    'orange'),
> (3,   'whatever',    'yellow'),
> (6,   'etc',         'yellow');
>
> select *
> from   @t
> order by (case when colour = 'yellow' then  1
>                when colour = 'orange' then 0
>                else 2
>            end);
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name     | colour
> -: | :------- | :-----
>  2 | stuff    | orange
>  5 | nonsense | orange
>  3 | whatever | yellow
>  6 | etc      | yellow
>  1 | this     | red   
>  4 | that     | red
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=e7e2de590e3337234b91c75199bc83c1)*

> ```
> create table foo(id int, name varchar(20), colour varchar(10));
> insert into foo values
> (1,   'this',        'red'),
> (4,   'that',        'red'),
> (2,   'stuff',       'orange'),
> (5,   'nonsense',    'orange'),
> (3,   'whatever',    'yellow'),
> (6,   'etc',         'yellow');
>
> create table bar(colour varchar(10), [order] int);
> insert into bar values
> ('orange', 0),
> ('yellow', 1),
> ('red', 2);
>
>
>
> select *
> from   foo
> inner join bar
> on foo.colour = bar.colour
> order by bar.[order];
>
>
> GO
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name     | colour | colour | order
> -: | :------- | :----- | :----- | ----:
>  2 | stuff    | orange | orange |     0
>  5 | nonsense | orange | orange |     0
>  3 | whatever | yellow | yellow |     1
>  6 | etc      | yellow | yellow |     1
>  1 | this     | red    | red    |     2
>  4 | that     | red    | red    |     2
> ```

*dbfiddle [here](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2016&fiddle=c8eff3647849e4cb60985b6629a73261)*